# Checkboxes in MFC listbox are appearing differently in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I have a simple MFC application in VS2010 and I am trying to move this app to VS2015 environment.

I am able to build the project successfully in VS2015. But the checkboxes in the application are appearing different than the VS2010.

I am using **CCheckListBox** class and  **create** method of CCheckListBox to create the checkboxes. Window style and List Box style used as below while creating checkboxes: 
 { WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL | LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT } 
Also I am using SetCheckStyle method with BS_AUTOCHECKBOX option.

MFC app built with VS2015:

[image]

MFC app built with VS2010:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? The code is exactly same.

Is MFC supported in VS2015?

Comment: Yes, MFC is supported in VS2015 (otherwise you woudln't have been able to build the application). We need some more information. How are the checkboxes displayed? Are you using the [`CCheckListBox `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d58s8sak.aspx) class?

Comment: I suggest [enabling visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx), unless you have a very good reason not to? It might already fix your issue.

Comment: Yes, I am using CCheckListBox.@MichaelWalz

Comment: I am using **create** method of CCheckListBox with Window style and List Box style as below:
{ WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED |                        LBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL | LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL |                     LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT}

Also I am using SetCheckStyle method with BS_AUTOCHECKBOX option.@MichaelWalz

Comment: @Eric_Cartman for clarifications please edit your question instead of posting comments..

Comment: Other hint: create a small test application with a CCheckListBox from scratch with VS2015 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a "state of the art" fix but I patched this bug with the following line :

`SetWindowTheme(m_boards.GetSafeHwnd(), L"Explorer", "L");`

In my dialog's `OnInitDialog()` method where m_board is a member `CheckListBox` binded to my list box control in the `DoDataExchange()` method.

You might want to use another theme than Explorer though.